# Unwind segue to a view controller that has not been called before

Tags: ios, swift, segue, logout, unwind-segue

There are 3 view controllers that come into play here 
(A) log in screen which comes after a splash screen 
(B) home page which comes after logging in 
(C) settings page from home page and contains a log out button.

The user log in info is saved so they don't have to sign in every time. Here is the code in the splash screen:

```
 Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                self.perform(#selector(self.goToLoginScreen), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
            } else {
                self.perform(#selector(self.goToHomeScreen), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)

            }
        }
```

I have the log out button which signs out the user from firebase and unwinds a segue to the log in screen.

```
 @objc func signoutPressed (sender: AnyObject) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("sign out is working")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToLogIn", sender: self)

        }
        catch {
            print("error signing out")
        }
    }
```

My issue is that the log out unwind segue only works if the user signed in in the same session but if its a returning user (didn't log in) the unwind segue doesn't work. How can I get this to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a na igation controller?  If so then you will need to insert the relevant view controller not the `viewControllers` array

Comment: Provide error what you are getting.